# Azure JavaScript function read from CosmosDb connects but query times out with no output

Tags: javascript, function, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm learning Azure functions and CosmosDb for a work project. I believe I have worked out most of what I need but my Azure JS function query is running but timing out and returning nothing. Following is my full function code, my log out put and a clip of the CosmosDb Data Explorer showing the data. You can see by the logging output the query is executing, but it always times out.

I'm passing: monsterId=5cc1b65f7dfa950cd42a5b8e on the querystring.

```js
let mongoClient = null;

module.exports = (context, req) => {
 const monsterId = req.query.monsterId;
 if (!monsterId) {
  context.res = {
   status: 400,
   body: "Please pass a 'monsterId' in the query string"
  };
  context.done();
 } else {
  function runQuery() {
   // Run the getMonster query
   const query = {
    "id": monsterId,
    "del": false
   };
            context.log('Running query now...');
   mongoClient.db('mfw-dev').collection('monsters')
    .findOne(query)
    .then(doc => {
     context.res = {
      body: { "monster": doc },
     };
     context.done();
    }, error => {
     context.err('Monster find error: ', error);
     context.res = {
      status: 400,
      body: { "error": "Monster find error: " + error },
     };
     context.done();
    });
  };

  if (mongoClient != null) {
      runQuery();
        } else {
   mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
   const uri = process.env.COSMOS_CONN;
   mongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(client => {
     context.log('MongoClient connected!!!...');
     //mongoClient = client;
     runQuery();
    }, error => {
     context.err('MongoClient connect error: ', error);
     context.res = {
      status: 400, /* Defaults to 200 */
      body: { "message": "MongoClient connect error: " + error },
     };
     context.done();
    });
  }
 }

};
```

[image: Azure function log output]

[image]

Comment: If you log out `doc` does it have a result? Only anomaly I can see there is it's the one response you don't set a `status` on....although, I'd be surprised if that's what caused it to hang.

Comment: I added a context.log(doc) in the query `.then(doc...` and it's never hit. Either the promise is not working as expected (because I've coded it wrong?) or the query is literally never returning anything. Not a success nor an error. Just timing out.

Comment: I think the problem here is you aren't use the connected client instance but rather the static client, to prove that theory you should reinstate the line `mongoClient = client`. Part of the issue I think is just in general the layout of your code, you should consider moving towards more of an `async` / `await` layout which should help write more synchronous code and get rid of the callback hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is you are querying using the *static* Mongo client and not the returned, connected, instance. In general, this all looks a lot more convoluted than it needs to be.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const { COSMOS_CONN } = process.env;
let client = null;

module.exports = async (context, req) => {
  const monsterId = req.query.monsterId;
  if (monsterId) {
    client = client || await MongoClient.connect(COSMOS_CONN, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    context.log('Running query now...');
    const monster = await client
      .db('mfw-dev')
      .collection('monsters')
      .findOne({
        id: monsterId,
        del: false
      });
    context.res = {
      body: { monster },
    };
  } else {
    context.res = {
        status: 400,
        body: "Please pass a 'monsterId' in the query string"
    };
  }
};
```

You'll notice the main differences here are:

- I'm not calling `context.done` anywhere
- I'm not handling any errors

This is because `context.done` is automatically called when the `async` function is complete, and if at any point any of the `async` calls throw, the error is caught and logged automatically.

One point to note is you maybe would want something a bit more robust around the MongoClient setup i.e. it's probably best to check that the client exists *and* connected, but I'll leave you to do the nitty gritty :)

Comment: Thank you for that! Questions: What is the var `client` in above code? Where/when is that set?

Comment: @Locohost whoops, that is meant to be `db`  in fact I'll rename `db` instead since `db.db(...)` would look odd

Comment: Oh and yes I agree, I much prefer the async/await style. I'm coming from Firebase cloud functions so I did not have that.

Comment: One note: Looks like without the context.done() lines, the context.log lines never write anything to log.

Comment: @Locohost hmm that's odd - I've got multiple functions that don't call `context.done` and logging works fine, possibly a timing issue?

Comment: You're right again @James. I reloaded the function app and now the context.logs are displaying fine :-)